# Rails create associated models without saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, in-memory

Say we have the models Patient and PatientRawData (with a belongs_to association to Patient).

Is it possible to create new records (without saving them in database), associate them, and finally save them in the database?

Something like this:

```
patient = Patient.new(:name => 'John', :age => 34)
rawtext = PatientRawText.new(:rawtext => 'My name is..')
patient.rawtext = rawtext
patient.save!
```

The reason I want to do this, is that in my real case scenario there might more complex models/associations and I would prefer to not have partial things in the database in case of an exception.

For this reason I prefer to build whatever complex thing I want, and as a final step to store the whole thing in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transaction` to prevent a bunch of records being created. It will roll back all ActiveRecord saves if an exception occurs anywhere in the block.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  patient = Patient.new(:name => 'John', :age => 34)
  rawtext = PatientRawText.create!(:rawtext => 'My name is..')
  patient.rawtext = rawtext
  patient.save! # <- if this fails
  raise "I don't want to be here"  # <- or if you manually raise an exeption 
end
```

If an exception is raised, even after the PatientRawText object was successfully created (say if `patient.save!` fails) then the PatientRawText creation will be rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

Rails have out of the box support for this type of issues using nested attributes.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :patient_raw_text
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patient_raw_text
end

params = { patient: { name: 'Jack', patient_raw_text_attributes: { rawtext: '...' } }}
member = Patient .create(params[:patient])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `new` on the instance's reference will create an unsaved associated model whose foreign key will be automatically assigned when the parent is saved. In other words...

```
patient = Patient.new(:name => 'John', :age => 34)
patient.patient_raw_text.new(:rawtext => 'My name is..')
patient.save!
```

It's the same as you suggested...just saves a line and local variable assignment

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Rails allows we do that:

```
patient = Patient.new(:name => 'John', :age => 34)
patient.build_patient_raw_text(:rawtext => 'My name is..')
patient.save!
```

Comment: This method doesn't exist.